# Apple IAP - How to validate the receipt?

Tags: java, ios, in-app-purchase, receipt

Here is the code that I use to validate IAP transaction receipt. 
httpsURLConnection.getOutputStream() throws SocketException: Connection reset.
What is that am missing?

public class HttpsClient {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject
                .put("receipt-data",
                        "encodeReceipt");

        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        try {
            String url = "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt";
            con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();

            HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) con;
            httpsURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStreamWriter wr = null;
            wr = new OutputStreamWriter(httpsURLConnection.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(jsonObject.toString());
            wr.flush();

            // Get the response
            httpsURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    httpsURLConnection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.print(line);
            }
            rd.close();

            System.out.println(httpsURLConnection);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Problem with corporate firewall. Sorted it out!